# Error Loading Media file now found

Tags: javascript, path, jwplayer

I have embed jwplayer but it does not playing video

here is code ..

```
   <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
     jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "http://50.6.232.19/asad/veronica/SafeTStop_demo.flv",
        image: ""
    });
</script>
```

Thank You

Comment: The `file` URL doesn't point to an flv file when I load it.  There are also JavaScript errors on the page.

Comment: but file is on the server in veronica directory.please tell me where are javascript errors..

Comment: Perhaps it is, but when I hit that URL, I see an HTML page with JavaScript errors. Take a look at the HTML source of the page and your JavaScript console.

Comment: Do you have a link to where this code is running?

Comment: I would advise updating, you are using 4.1, which is 4+ years old.